# Installing Connect 2.0 extensions via SSH

Tags: magento-connect

How do I install a Connect 2.0 extension to my local development box without using the /downloader UI? How can I script this in a deployment routine?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Installing via SSH:**

Obtain the Connect 2.0 key via Magento Connect:

[image]

Ensure that `mage` is executable from your Magento root:

`chmod +x ./mage`

Execute `./mage install` and paste your extension key immediately after the word 'install' - remove the slash between 'community' and your extension package name. E.g.:

`./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community OnePica_AvaTax`

^ Notice the lack of a slash between 'community' and 'OnePica_AvaTax'.

To script into a deployment - issue the `./mage install` command from your build. This should sync all production servers to have record of the community module install which should make removing or upgrading the module in the future scriptable as well (without necessitating a commit to your version control system).

Answer (score 3):

> How do I install a Connect 2.0 extension to my local development box without using the /downloader UI?

Check out http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

It allows you to download modules directly using extension keys (1.0 or 2.0). Then move the module files into place.

Comment: Yeah - I've seen that. While it's interesting, part of me gets nervous that I'm downloading production code from an unknown site. I (perhaps falsely) feel safer having downloaded and installed directly from Magento Connect or via the downloader ui.

Comment: mm... good point ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ./mage which is in your directory root eg:(/var/www/).
Give access to mage by entering following command:

sudo chmod 775 mage

Get a magento connect key from the website and install it using the following example.
Example magento connect key: http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/PACKAGENAME

./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community PACKAGENAME

Answer (score 1):

Better variant than the one proposed by kevnk is to use https://www.magentokey.com/

It allows you all same things as freegento, but also you can download any version of extension. You will also get links directly from magentocommerce.com, so it's safer.

Comment: Welcome to Magento.SE! Thanks for your answer. Just a quick heads-up this is a 4-year-old question; and the question specifically requested SSH capability, this answer doesn't add any value. Further, self-promotion is generally frowned upon - if this is your domain or your product you should disclose it when answering. Please proceed with caution.